# Write mathematical equation in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, plugins, equations

I am working on a math quiz using flash CS3 with ActionScript 3.0

I have the source document in Microsoft Word. They have all been typed in equation nicely.

I cannot copy them straight into flash document.

I do not want to printscreen those equation. There a lot of fraction,index and symbols.

Is there a way so that I can copy the equations straight into flash?

Is there something like, install plug in so that flash can read it?

Comment: Unlikely, you'd better to use image for the equation IMHO.

Comment: then the final swf file will be huge if i make them all images.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [LaTeX2SWF](http://www.tlhiv.org/LaTeX2swf/) library instead of trying to import Microsoft Equation directly.
[Example here](http://www.flashandmath.com/basic/latex/index.html)

If you can't download it, you can try something like [this](http://validi.fi/latex2flash/)

You should also convert all of your Math Equations from Microsoft format to LaTeX. There are a lot of automated programs and plugins, like [this](http://www.wordtolatex.com/blog/how-to-convert-mathtype-equations-and-microsoft-word-equations-to-latex/), but there are lots of others

Comment: so i must first word-to-LaTeX then latex-to-flash using LaTeX2Symbol? thanks!

Comment: @Juniki Takuya absolutely wright

If it helped you, feel free to mark this question as accepted ;)

Comment: @KumoKairo..this is frustrating..:( i have converted word to latex but the latextosymbol is in cs5 and mine is cs3..

Comment: i have also search for online converter but i dont quite get it..from latex we want to change into "what" format so that i can copy it to my flash document i am working on?sorry for being a bother..:(